# How to remove strings and punctuation from a columns using SAS or PROC SQL?

Tags: sas, proc-sql, regex-replace

I have a column with a lot of company names without any cleaning as below. But I want to do the cleaning to remove a list of strings from company names so I can group them together.

list of strings: com,llc,ltd,corp,stores

```
| Company |
| --- |
| Amazon |
| Amazon.com |
| Amazon.llc |
| Amazon.ltd |
| Amazon corp |
| Amazon stores |
```

I also want to remove punctuation and strip spaces from the company names, so the desired outcome can be like:

```
| Company |
| --- |
| Amazon |
| Amazon |
| Amazon |
| Amazon |
| Amazon |
| Amazon |
```

I have done my project using Python but I need to convert it to SAS or PROC SQL, but I'm not familiar with these 2 languages, so appreciate any help.

Comment: Also look into COMPGED for fuzzy matching options, as the Amazon is simple enough but Best Buy versus Best Buy America LTD is slightly harder as is IBM versus International Business Machines. If you have SAS DQ Studio it has tools to do this but it's not available in SAS Base (9.4/Viya)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression should make this easy:

`([\. ])(com|ltd|llc|corp|stores)`

https://regex101.com/r/FhnEwN/1

In SAS, finding and replacing strings with regex is done with the `prxchange` function, which works like this:

`string = prxchange('s/regex here/replacement string/', times, string);`

Where `times` is the number of replacements you want to make. -1 means to replace every match. If you leave your replacement string as a null value, like this: `'s/regex here//'` then you will effectively remove the matched value.

Converting it to SAS:

```
data want;
    set have;
    company = prxchange('s/([\. ])(com|ltd|llc|corp|stores)//', -1, company);
run;
```

```
Company
Amazon
Amazon
Amazon
Amazon
Amazon
Amazon
```